# WSO2 EI - Data Source not connecting to External database, but Data Service does

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Current Server Version - >  6.1.1

I am able to connect to an External Oracle Database when I create a data source through "Configure" --> Data Sources.

But I am able to connect to the same Oracle database when I try to create a Data Service and add data source.

Is there something we might be missing in setup.

**Data Service Code:**

```
   <data name="OracleDataService">
       <config enableOData="false" id="Oracledb">
          <property name="driverClassName">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
      <property name="url">jdbc:oracle:thin:<username>/<password>@myhost:2070<mysid></property>
   </config>
   <query id=""
.............../>
```

This works perfectly and pulls data out of my database. 
When I attempt tp create a Data Source under "Configure --> Datasources --> Add datasource" Code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasource>
   <name>oracledb</name>
   <definition type="RDBMS">
      <configuration>
         <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
         <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:<username>/<password>@myhost:2070</url>
      </configuration>
   </definition>
</datasource>
```

I get this error:

```
TID[-1234] [EI] [2018-09-11 16:34:34,056] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceRepository} - Error establishing data source connection: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader.testDataSourceConnection(RDBMSDataSourceReader.java:87) org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceRepository.testDataSourceConnection(DataSourceRepository.java:512) org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.services.NDataSourceAdminService.testDataSourceConnection(NDataSourceAdminService.java:89) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212) org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117) org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40) org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110) org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169) org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82) org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45) org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77) org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442) org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430) org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225) org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149) org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.ui.stub.NDataSourceAdminStub.testDataSourceConnection(NDataSourceAdminStub.java:1142) org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.ui.NDataSourceAdminServiceClient.testDataSourceConnection(NDataSourceAdminServiceClient.java:88) org.apache.jsp.ndatasource.validateconnection_002dajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(validateconnection_002dajaxprocessor_jsp.java:99) org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155) org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.URLBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(URLBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:57) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:61) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110) org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47) org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159) org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452) org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087) org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1760) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1719) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you post your configuration for the data service you have created, and the error message you are getting?

Comment: Just by asking questions it's not possible for anyone to resolve, you need to provide certain configurations and code along with the log files so that people can help you out.

Comment: Edited. Appreciate your response.